# Is it possible to make C++ platform independent by making it run inside a VM just like in Java?

Tags: c++, jvm, virtual-machine, portability

Given that Java is highly portable and it is not having serious overheads, can't C++ be made platform independent?

Comment: Java's VM is not written in Java. It gets its claimed portability from being written in C++.

Comment: Note: Java is "not having serious overheads" only because of ~20 years of work on the JVM.

Comment: I read that Java can outperform C++ these days on most tasks because the compiler optimizes so aggressively for JVM. C++ compilers do not enjoy this level of guaranteed information about the hardware they are running on.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII While some people say this, reality shows that Java usually can't reach C++, given that both programs are equally well optimized (compiler options, proper algorithms, manual optimization) (ie. a good Java program being faster than a badly written C++ program is nothing noteworthy)

Comment: @deviantfan. no crap java can't get to C++, I was just saying how in practice for day to day tasks java is a very capable platform.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Instead of such an reaction, read your own comment again, eg. the first sentence. You read something and seem to believe it. If you don't, why did you write it in the first place?

Comment: @deviantfan I said on "most tasks". still C++ will win if compiler knows what architecture it is running on exactly.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII And I was saying that this information isn't even necessary (other than knowing enough to be able to generate an executable program at all, of course), and C++ still wins (for most tasks). Well, whatever...

Comment: How is this opinion based? The CLI is very similar to the JVM and also cross platform. There are C++ compilers which target the CLI. Ergo, you can make C++ platform independent by making it run inside a VM just like in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. For example, you can compile C++ to JavaScript ( see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197940/how-to-run-c-code-in-browser-using-asm-js ) or to CLI byte code ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI ) to run on Windows or Linux, or various other targets.

None of these currently performs as well as native C++, and most lack direct access to operating system resources. So the portability comes at some cost, and usually if you wanted to pay the cost of targeting web browsers or CLI, you have languages better suited to those platforms.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, the method of code execution (whether the code is compiled, interpreted, run by VM, etc) is more a property of the implementation, and not the language.

when people say C++ is a compiled language and that JavaScript is an interpreted language, that does not necessarily mean that you can't write a compiler that translates JavaScript code to machine code on your hardware of choice, but rather what is a common way to provide implementation for said language.

In practice, C++ is used because of its efficiency and close to the metal features that is a good choice for performance critical tasks like embedded systems programming, systems programming, graphics, etc, so getting C++ to run in a VM would defeat its purpose. 
kinda like buying a fillet Mignon and cooking it in the microwave.

Answer (score 0):

Java compiles to an intermediate platform-independent byte code that is then interpreted at runtime by platform-specific JVMs.  That is what allows Java to be portable.  Each type of JVM is tailored to run the byte code on the platform's particular hardware architecture.

C/C++ compiles to native machine code that runs directly on the CPU (or as directly as the OS will allow).  So no, you cannot compile C/C++ in a platform-independent manner.  You have to use platform-specific compilers to compile C/C++ code for each hardware architecture that you want to run your code on.

Comment: There's no fundamental reason someone can't make a C++ compiler that emits an intermediate platform-independent bytecode.

Comment: @immibis: True, but then you would still need a platform-specific runtime to actually run that bytecode on each machine/device. Unless you are thinking about compiling C++ to Java bytecode and letting a Java JVM run it, for instance.

Comment: If the JVM counts as "platform-independent", then so does a hypothetical C++ bytecode VM.